# How can I write to a file using fs.appendSyncFile (writing to raspberry pi server)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to create a blacklist command for my bot, that prevents users from using commands if they are on the list,  i got the part where the bot reads the list and checks if your ID is there, but im having trouble making it so that the bot writes to the txt file, take a look

```
} else if(message.startsWith('?blacklist')) {
    if(message.author.id == USERID){
        fs.appendFileSync('/home/pi/Desktop/bot/blacklist.txt', 'utf8', args[1] + '\n');
        message.channel.send('Alright, ive blocked this user!');
```

Its purpose is to take what the user inputs `?blacklist 420420420420` and blocks it adds `420420420420` to the list "blacklist.txt"
it doesn't seem to be doing that and im not getting any errors on my logs so im wondering if i can get help here

Comment: are you missing a leading `/` in `home/pi/Desktop/bot/blacklist.txt`

Comment: no, i am not, if i did that, i checked the logs and it just said the same thing

Comment: though i did edit it because i do believe that would have been a different error

Comment: is the node process running as user `pi` - if not, do the permissions on file blacklist.txt allow other users to write? do the permissions on the folders (pi, pi/Desktop, pi/Desktop/bot) also allow user other than `pi` access

Comment: "i do believe that would have been a different error" - different error suggests you HAVE an error - but you don't HAVE an error

Answer (score 0):

`message.startsWith` isn't a function
it needs to be `args[1].startsWith'

for the message ID i needed to have it put as `args.slice(1).join(' ')`

and i needed to remove 'utf8' as you can not encode writes